# Perform merge in 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes as below:

```
Dataframe1:
i   j
3   4
5   6
7   2

Dataframe2:
k   n
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
7   g
8   h
```

How do I merge these 2 dataframes such that the key element is both i and j on the fist dataframe and k on the second dataframe such that the result is:

```
Dataframe1:
i   j   ni   nj
3   4   c   d
5   6   e   f
7   2   g   b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), also is necessary column `k` has to be unique:

```
s = df2.set_index('k')['n']
df1['ni'] = df1['i'].map(s)
df1['nj'] = df1['j'].map(s)
print (df1)

   i  j ni nj
0  3  4  c  d
1  5  6  e  f
2  7  2  g  b
```

Answer (score 4):

***Option 1***

- Build a mapping dictionary with `dict` and `zip`
- Use `applymap` with the dictionary's `get` method
- Use `add_prefix` to get the `'n'` in front
- Use `join` to merge

---

```
m = dict(zip(d2.k.values, d2.n.values))
d1.join(d1.applymap(m.get).add_prefix('n'))

   i  j ni nj
0  3  4  c  d
1  5  6  e  f
2  7  2  g  b
```

---

**Equivalent 1-line**

```
d1.join(d1.applymap(dict(zip(d2.k.values, d2.n.values)).get).add_prefix('n'))

   i  j ni nj
0  3  4  c  d
1  5  6  e  f
2  7  2  g  b
```

---

***Option 2***
*Same as option 1 except we could use a `stack`/`unstack` idiom with `map`*

```
m = dict(zip(d2.k.values, d2.n.values))
d1.join(d1.stack().map(m).unstack().add_prefix('n'))

   i  j ni nj
0  3  4  c  d
1  5  6  e  f
2  7  2  g  b
```

Comment: That's a really beautiful solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach, using [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), and [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot):

```
df3 = (df1.unstack('j')
          .reset_index()
          .rename(columns={0:'k'})
          .merge(df2, on="k")
          .pivot(index='level_1', columns='level_0'))
df3.columns = ['{}{}'.format(a,b) if a == 'n' else b for a,b in df3.columns]
df3.set_index(['i','j'], inplace=True)

    ni nj
i j      
3 4  c  d
5 6  e  f
7 2  g  b
```